# Can group name of a user and the username of some other user be the same?

Tags: linux, users, group

Let's say the group name of user1 is xyz.

Is it possible, in the same Linux machine, that the username of some other user (not user1) is xyz?

Comment: for extra confusion: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287079/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but I wouldn't recommend it as it would be confusing.

Actually it is common practice in most UNIXes and Linux distros, when user xyz is created, to automatically create a group named xyz and assign to it user xyz as its (only) member.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually common practice to create group with the same name as user. For example there is root account and root group. Check **/etc/group** and **/etc/passwd** files to see it. Check also this two nixCraft pages to get to know more about those files:

[Understanding /etc/passwd File Format](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)
[Understanding /etc/group File](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/)

User account and user group is not combined with each other anwhere else than in /etc/passwd file. So you can have:

```
user1:x:0:0:user2:/root:/bin/bash
user2:x:0:0:user1:/root:/bin/bash
```

but I think it can be a little bit confusing.