# Valid special characters allowed in a CentOS 7 username?

Tags: centos, users

I'm trying to figure out how CentOS 7 identifies what is considered a valid character in a naming convention when a user account is created.

I was playing around with useradd to confirm my understanding of what CentOS considered valid characters in a user name.... and to my surprise the useradd command accepted '_' and '.'... Which got me wondering where valid/invalid characters are established in CentOS

The useradd man page in CentOS doesn't mention valid characters... And google searches said this is done with NAME_REGEX (For ubuntu at least)... and had me looking for it in a adduser.conf file... which does not exist in CentOS 7... I haven't been able to locate a CentOS/Red Hat specific source on google about this... But I've also looked in /etc/login.defs and /etc/default/useradd with no luck

Can anyone direct me to the mechanism in CentOS does this?

Comment: Related, over at SO (for whatever reason): [What are the real rules for linux usernames on CentOS 6 and RHEL 6?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6949667)

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287077/117549

Answer (score 2):

Note that `useradd` may be more restrictive than what is actually valid as a username.   The rules as to what a valid username is may also *change* via PAM and nsswitch configuration settings.

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437) says that usernames must be from the "portable filename characterset" but the first character must not be a hyphen.

The [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) are the characters A-Z a-z 0-9 . - _

Note this means that something like "1337" is a valid username according to this standard, which may cause issues elsewhere.

So, for safety, I would use a pattern such as [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9._-]+