# How to fix "Account starting with zero"

Tags: rhel, mailx

Because this company uses Centrify, I made a local Oracle account starting with zero on another server so as not to conflict with the original.

No problem except when my scripts email me I get:

```
Local Oracle Account starting with zero <0racle@hostname>
```

It's just annoying and a google search didn't turn up anything useful on making this more readable.

Can I change what I see in the email?

EDIT_1:
Adding a picture
[image]

Comment: What is your mail server?

Comment: Related: [Why can't Linux usernames begin with numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287077/315749)

Comment: @Romeo Ninov  Not sure what you are asking?  Sending an email from this linux machine eventually ends up in a MS Exchange server and to my inbox.

Comment: @fra-san  Point taken.  My bad.  Since what is done is done...any workaround possible?

Comment: @Marinaio, try to rename the user. Or create new one to replace current.

Comment: @Marinaio If I understand it correctly, you are going to live with your `0racle` user and the possibility that some program will misbehave. But it is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to stop receiving those emails in your inbox? Have you got any further information about what is sending them?

Comment: @fra-san 1. Yes, I have to live with the user starting with zero, "0racle".  2. When the system emails it looks like the picture I just posted.  I want change "local Oracle account starting with zero" to Oracle or some other text.  It just is confusing to anyone but me.

Comment: I thought "Local Oracle Account starting with zero" was part of the email text, while it now looks like it's used as the sender's name. Is it the user's full name as specified in `/etc/passwd`? Can you just change it (e.g. using `chfn -f "new name" 0racle`)?