# how to add new user username must be in numeric in red hat linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel

I want to add new user in red hat linux.Username must be in numeric i.e username 123456.I was trying to add but its given invalid user name so it is possible to add new username only in numeric.

Comment: Looks like this is deprecated in RHEL 7 and unavailable on RHEL 8: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532723/173368

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Linux usernames begin with numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/why-cant-linux-usernames-begin-with-numbers)

Comment: @AdminBee Interesting that REL8 [allows](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index#all-numeric-user-group-names_security) usernames to begin with a dot. Imagine the difficulties if your username was `.` or `..`.

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion for accomplishing this which in non conventional, would be to create a valid user such as *a23456* using the `adduser` command, for example:

```
adduser a23456 --uid 123456 --gid users --groups users --create-home --comment firstname\ lastname
```

Then manually edit `/etc/passwd` **and** `/etc/shadow` and change the first character on the corresponding line from an `a` to a `1` for the username to meet your needs.

What may break or not work in RHEL after that I don't know.

Whether you change the home directory name to match is up to you.

double check the `/home/a23456` or `/home/123456` home directory ownership and make sure it matches what is in `/etc/passwd` for uid and gid.

Answer (score 0):

If you go low level, you can add non-standard names.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> is your friend, at least on Debian or Ubuntu), and check the manpage (stop with `q`):

```
man useradd
```

You will find an option `--badname`, so something like `useradd --badname`  should work.

Good luck. I'm not accepting any liability.

Comment: This answer should be tagged `ubuntu` (and not just for opening the terminal). REL systems along with some other distributions don't support `--badnames`.

Comment: @doneal24 : on the other hand : REL systems do have `--badname`



    `me@somevm:/home/me >uname -a
    Linux somevm 5.14.0-165.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Sep 17         14:08:33 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    me@somevm:/home/me >cat /etc/centos-release 
    CentOS Stream release 9
    me@somevm:/home/me >man useradd | grep -A 1 bad
           --badname
               Allow names that do not conform to standards.
    me@somevm:/home/me >`